# SELECT and COUNT from two différents tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm using phpMyAdmin and I've two SQL tables:

___SalesTaxes

```
|--------|----------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_Name | STX_Amount |
|--------|----------|------------|
|      1 |    Tax 1 |       5.00 |
|      2 |    Tax 2 |      13.50 |
|--------|----------|------------|
```

___Inventory

```
|--------|----------|----------|---------------------|
| INV_Id | INV_Name | INV_Rate | INV_ApplicableTaxes |
|--------|----------|----------|---------------------|
|     10 |     Bike |     9.00 |                   1 |
|     11 |    Movie |     3.00 |                 1,2 |
|--------|----------|----------|---------------------|
```

*INV_ApplicableTaxes list the applicable taxes.*

For each item in the `___Inventory` table, I have the table `___SalesTaxes` linked to know witch taxes is applicable to the item.

How can I list items in `___Inventory` and sum applicable taxes to have something like this:

- Bike - Applicable sum of taxes is 5.00%
- Movie - Applicable sum of taxes is 18.50%

What I already tried is:

```
SELECT 
    a.INV_ApplicableTaxes, 
    (
        SELECT Count(b.STX_Amount) 
        FROM ___SalesTaxes 
        Where b.STX_Id = a.INV_ApplicableTaxes
    ) as b_count 
FROM  ___Inventory
```

Thanks.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik, i'm using phpMyAdmin. Hope phpMyAdmin is a rdbms.

Comment: @roro do you know `inner join` phrase? I think it will help you.

Comment: @roro phpMyAdmin is an administration tool for [tag:mysql]. I've edited your question to add it to the tags.

Comment: @roro I suggest you change your database design.  It's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very poor data structure.  You should not be storing `1,2` in a single column.  Why not?

- Integers should be stored as integers, not strings.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- SQL has relatively poor string handling functions.
- The SQL optimizer cannot optimize string operations very well, particularly between tables.

The proper way to store this would be using a separate `itemTaxes` table, with one row per item and one row per applicable tax.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions and can't do anything about it (until performance is so bad that we have to).

You can do what you want using `like`:

```
SELECT i.INV_ApplicableTaxes, 
       (SELECT SUM(st.STX_Amount) 
        FROM ___SalesTaxes st
        WHERE ',' || st.STX_Id || ',' LIKE '%,' || i.INV_ApplicableTaxes || ',%'
       ) as sum_taxes 
FROM  ___Inventory i;
```

Note:  This uses ANSI standard syntax for string concatenation.  Some databases have their own syntax.

EDIT:

In MySQL, you can express this using `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT i.INV_ApplicableTaxes, 
       (SELECT SUM(st.STX_Amount) 
        FROM ___SalesTaxes st
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(st.STX_Id, i.INV_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
       ) as sum_taxes 
FROM  ___Inventory i;
```

Comment: Hello, problem with your solution is the query gave me always the same result for `sum_taxes`. If one or two taxes should be applied, the same sum is returned (i.e.: 18.50).

Comment: @roro . . . Given that the ANSI-standard syntax doesn't work in MySQL, you probably made a transcription error.  MySQL has a short-cut, `find_in_set()` to facilitate this.  However, that does not change the fact that you should fix the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Looking forward, this is quite a questionable design for a database, and sooner or later, the lack of 1NF normalization may very well cause you problems.

However, if changing the database schema is not an option, you could use the [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to help perform this join:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELECT SUM(s.stx_amount) 
        FROM   ___SalesTaxes s
        WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(s.stx_id, i.inv_applicableTaxes) > 0
       ) AS total_tax
FROM  ___Inventory i
```

Comment: Hello, phpMyAdmin returns me this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT SUM(b.STX_Amount) 
        FROM   ___SalesTaxes s
        WHERE  find_' at line 2`

Comment: @roro arg, was missing a `,` after the `*`. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Hello, I've got now `#1054 - Unknown column 'b.STX_Amount' in 'field list'`.

Comment: should have been `i`, sorry

Comment: `SUM(i.stx_amount)` should be `SUM(s.stx_amount)`.

Comment: @roro arg, indeed